# 0/0 in C - gcc-7 or higher

Tags: c, debugging

Mathematically, `0 / 0` is undefined. But, in C programming (especially `gcc` compiler gcc-7.3.0 on ubuntu), it produces the answer as `1`. I would like to know the reason. Is it working by repeated subtraction? For, the same code, if I use `n = 1 / n`, I get a floating point exception. However, for gcc-5.3.0, it produces an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    n = n - 5;
    switch (n) {
    case 0:
        printf("n= %d", n);
        n = n / n;
        printf("n calc= %d", n);
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("n=5");
        break;
    default:
        printf("n=1");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior (division by 0) is undefined.

Comment: But, neither produces compilation error, nor any runtime error in gcc>7

Comment: @panch: undefined behavior (by the C standard) does not mean and error (static or at runtime) has to be generated. It could also mean that a random number is returned (1 in this case). Probably the compiler does so in course of optimizing n/n and replacing it by 1.

Comment: You can check this code in https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler, gcc-8.1.0 or 7.2.0

Comment: Doing full control-flow analytics of a program is *hard*, and left to static analyzers. The compiler generates executable code from your source under the assumption that there's no undefined behaviors. If there is, then all bets are off.

Comment: @panch I got a runtime error [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44c0235f40e98e23) with a slightly different code. Again, it's undefined. You can get any effect, including no error at all on some or all platforms.

Comment: Then, in a large program, if there is a 0/0 and returns some random number, how a programmer can debug it, without knowing its explicit value.

Comment: By making sure the denominator is not 0 *before* doing any division. (`if (n != 0) a = 5 / n;` for example)

Comment: For 1/n you probably do not get a floating point exception, but a division by zero exception (which is for integers only). Floating point math is (on virtually all platforms) algebraically closed, that means all operations generate a valid output. (hence there are additional symbols Inf, Nan and signed zero)

Comment: @panch GCC and Clang have `-fsanitize=undefined` which catches division by zero: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ef496f6f34b032c

Comment: @AndreasH. Well, not really: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGFPE

Comment: @Bob__ These exceptions are optional and disabled by default. I have not seen any code that actually uses FP exceptions. Still all FP operations generate a valid output, there is no case where an FP exception handling is necessary as it is the case for division by zero in the integer case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by zero is undefined behavior in C programming (C11 6.5.5 §6). Meaning that there is no predictable result, there is no telling what your program might do.

It isn't very meaningful to try reason about why you get one particular outcome of "anything might happen". It might print 1, it might print 42, it might print nothing at all. The program might crash and burn. If you run the program twice, you might get different outcomes. And so on.

As for why you won't get a compiler error, the compiler isn't able or obliged to find or diagnose run-time errors. Most cases of undefined behavior need to be avoided by the programmer.

Some good compilers may be able to give warnings if you use pure integer constant expressions such as `int x = 0/0;`, but again it is not the job of the compiler to find this bug. It is the programmer's job. Therefore you should make a habit of always checking if the right operand of `/` or `%` is zero before applying the operands.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are allowed to assume that the code does not invoke undefined behavior, and use that assumption while optimizing the code.

For any value, other than `n==0` the expression `n/n` evaluates as 1. Since diving by zero is undefined behavior in C, the compiler can assume that this scenario never happens, i.e., it can assume that `n!=0`. 
Since it may assume that, the compiler can replace the slow `n/n` with the cheap constant value of `1`. This is probably what happens with the code in question.

Of course, the compiler is not required to make any such assumption, and might generate an actual division. Depending on the hardware that executes the code, a specific hardware signal (or exception) might be triggered in such a case of division by zero. I doubt that any reasonable compiler will emit division in this example for **optimized code**, because division is extremely slow, and according to the standard the constant `1` is good enough. However, it is still likely it will produce an actual division in debug mode.

Similar things happen when optimizing away other undefined behavior, such as `int` overflow:

```
void f(int x)
{
   if (x > x + 1) 
       // executed only in case of overflow,
       // which is undefined behavior, 
       // and hence likely optimized out.
       overflow_error();
   ...
```

Don't rely on undefined behavior - it is not predictable.

Comment: Similarly, the compiler is free to pass a divide by zero to the machine code, in which case you'd get some CPU-specific exception.

Comment: @Lundin of course it can emit a CPU-specific exception, and it probably does that in debug mode on many systems. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen on [Godbolt's compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/0u89gn), both `gcc` and `clang` optimize `n / n` for `n` integer to evaluate to `1` without any warning. `gcc` performs this optimisation **even** at `-O0` whereas `clang` generates the division opcode for `-O0` but the optimized alternative for `-O1` and above.

`0 / 0` has undefined behavior anyway, therefore any behavior for `n / n` is OK if `n` is zero, including evaluating to `1` without an observable side-effect.

If you insist, you could qualify `n` as `volatile` and the compiler might generate a division, as both `gcc` and `clang` do in this case, but as long as `n` is read twice, it does not have to.